# One Image to Rule Them All: why Facebook and AddThis do that?

Tags: javascript, facebook, image-manipulation, addthis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Single image file to store all the little images on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507665/single-image-file-to-store-all-the-little-images-on-a-page)

Hey,

Facebook are saving all the graphics on their page in a single [image](http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zA/r/2JxA2hFGRWc.png). So does [AddThis](http://s7.addthis.com/static/r07/widget27_32x32.png). Why do they do that? How can I use the same techniques and cut the images with JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do this so they can save connection overhead (otherwise browsers would open up a connection for every single image ~ if uncached).

You don't need javascript to *cut up* the image: use standard CSS positioning to show specific parts of the image.

Comment: Doesn't this mean (for addThis) adding the 32x12416 image several times to the page? How can you position this with CSS?

Comment: Your browser will download the image once and then use it's local copy. To position this with CSS have a look at the thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507665/single-image-file-to-store-all-the-little-images-on-a-page/507694#507694 or google for CSS sprites.

Answer (score 5):

they are called [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). It reduces the number of requests made to load the page, thus decreasing load time. The site can just set the background of something to be a small portion of the image.